# How to Upgrade Windows 10 64 bit from Windows 8.1 32 bit?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I have Window 8.1 32 bit installed in my lap. I want to Upgrade to Windows 10 64 bit version. How to do it? ( clean installation is OK)

Comment: Is your computer compatible with 64bit? Trying to figure out why you have a 32bit version of windows 8.1 and not a 64bit version installed. If your computer can handle the 64bit that is?

Comment: There is no upgrade path from 32bit to 64bit, you would need to clean install W10 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a clean installation either way. Assuming your machine is compatible with a 64 bit OS, either:

1. Clean install Windows 8.1, of the same edition you currently have, in 64 bit. Following this, upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

or

2. Clean install Windows 10 64 bit, of the corresponding edition, using an ISO *since* November 2015 (Build 1511).

The editions are as follows:

[image]

<sub>From [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/upgrade-to-windows-10-faq)</sub>

Comment: If I do a clean installation using iso can I use the windows 8.1 product key?

Comment: @Damith As long as you are using an ISO *since* November 2015, yes.